# Dart Enhanced Enum with non constant value

Tags: dart, enums

I am using enhanced enum feature of dart and created enum as below. But looks like it doesn't work with non-constant fields.

```dart
var dynamic="DYNAMIC";

enum TestEnum{
  john(name:"John"),
  doo(name:"John $dynamic");
  
  const TestEnum({required this.name});
  
  final String name;
}
```

In the second case `doo(name:"John $dynamic");` it gives error

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor. (Documentation)
```

I tried the following but doesn't work.
I tried removing the const and finals from the field.

```dart
enum TestEnum {
  john(name: "John"),
  doo(name: "John $dynamic");

   TestEnum({required this.name}); <-- removed const

   String name; <-- remove final
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the answer above and in documentation, all generative constructors must be constant and instant variables must be final. However if you want to achieve the expected result, you may use class instead of enum like this:

```
class TestEnum {
  factory TestEnum.john() => const TestEnum(name: 'John');
  factory TestEnum.doo({required dynamic dynamicVal}) =>
      TestEnum(name: 'John $dynamicVal');

  const TestEnum({required this.name});

  final String name;
}
```

This will work but it's technically *not* an enum.

```
final john = TestEnum.john().name; // John
final doo = TestEnum.doo(dynamic: 'DYNAMIC').name; // John DYNAMIC
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want an (always constant) enum value to return a non-constant value, you need to access it *in code*, which isn't run until runtime. The non-constant field can't be stored in an (required final) field or passed as a (required constant) constructor argument.

```dart
var dynamicValue = "DYNAMIC";

enum TestEnum{
  john(_name: "John"),
  doo(_name: "John %dynamic%");
  
  const TestEnum({required String name}) : _nameTemplate = name;
  
  final String _nameTemplate;

  String get name => _nameTemplate.replaceAll("%dynamic%", dynamicValue);
}

void main() {
  print(TestEnum.doo.name); // John DYNAMIC
  dynamicValue = "McJohnface";
  print(TestEnum.doo.name); // John McJohnface
}
```

You can add caching, if you only want to do the substitution the first time the value is read (cache in static map or list), like:

```dart
enum TestEnum{
  john(_name: "John"),
  doo(_name: "John %dynamic%");
  
  const TestEnum({required String name}) : _nameTemplate = name;
  
  final String _nameTemplate;

  String get name => _nameCache[index] ??=
      _nameTemplate.replaceAll("%dynamic%", dynamicValue);

  static final List<String?> _nameCache = List.filled(values.length, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All instances of your enum, must be able to be created when compiling your program, and each instance must be a const object where the state are immutable.

In your example, you can do the following if you want to have the prefix `String` declared outside your enum.

```dart
const String dynamic="DYNAMIC";

enum TestEnum{
  john(name:"John"),
  doo(name:"John $dynamic");

  const TestEnum({required this.name});

  final String name;
}
```

This works since we are allowed to concatenate other const `String` objects when building a const `String` object.

Comment: In my case the other string is not going to be const. Its localized string in flutter.
So based on your answer its not possible?